# Linear Programming in LaTeX: crosshatching the feasible region

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I have the following graph:

[image: Graph of a LP problem]

How can I crosshatch the feasible region?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid,
grid style={densely dashed},
axis line style={->},
axis lines=middle,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-1, xmax=10,
    ymin=-1, ymax=20,
    axis lines=center,
   axis on top=true,
   domain=0:100,
    ]
   \addplot [draw=red,thick] {15-2*x}; \addlegendentry{$6x + 3y \leq 45$}
    \addplot [draw=blue,thick] (x,16-4*x); \addlegendentry{$4x + y \leq 16$}
    \addplot [draw=green,thick] (x, 3*x); \addlegendentry{$3x \leq y$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create nodes at the intersection points and draw a filled, borderless triangle between those three points?

Comment: I posted an answer for the three inequations you provided. I think that the "green/blue" triangle would be the solution of this system only if the last one was 3x >= y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the intersections of the lines and then fill in between, but dividing it into two parts.

[image: Fillbetween]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        grid,
        grid style={densely dashed},
        axis line style={->},
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
            xmin=-1, xmax=10,
            ymin=-1, ymax=20,
            axis lines=center,
           axis on top=true,
           domain=0:10,
            ]
           \addplot [draw=red,thick,name path=A] {15-2*x}; \addlegendentry{$6x + 3y \leq 45$}
            \addplot [draw=blue,thick,name path=B] (x,16-4*x); \addlegendentry{$4x + y \leq 16$}
            \addplot [draw=green,thick,name path=C] (x, 3*x); \addlegendentry{$3x \leq y$}
            \addplot[olive!20] fill between[of=C and A,soft clip={domain=0:0.51}];
            \addplot[olive!20] fill between[of=B and C,soft clip={domain=0.5:16/7}];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You may notice that I didn't use `0.5` but `0.51` for the first fill, just to avoid a blank thin line between the two parts which sometimes appears on some PDF viewers (but should not).